# Bean Validation for exact string match

Tags: java, regex, javabeans, bean-validation

1. I want to validate a string for exact match in bean validation. Should I use `@Pattern` or is there a different method to do so?
2. If `@Pattern` is the way to go, what is the `regex`?
3. Can I use two  `@Pattern` annotation for two different groups on a same field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to validate a string for exact match in bean validation. Should I use @Pattern or is there a different method to do so?

You could either use `@Pattern` or implement a custom constraint very easily:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MatchesValidator.class)
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Matches {
    String message() default "com.example.Matches.message";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    String value();
}
```

With the validator like this:

```
public class MatchesValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Matches, String> {

    private String comparison;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Matches constraint) {
        this.comparison = constraint.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(
        String value,
        ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        return value == null || comparison.equals(value);
    }
}
```

> If `@Pattern` is the way to go, what is the `regex`?

Basically just the string you want to match, you only need to escape special characters such as [\^$.|?*+(). See [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for more details.

> Can I use two @Pattern annotation for two different groups on a same field?

Yes, just use the the `@Pattern.List` annotation:

```
@Pattern.List({
    @Pattern( regex = "foo", groups = Group1.class ),
    @Pattern( regex = "bar", groups = Group2.class )
})
```

Comment: E.g. `@Pattern( regex = "foo" )` or `@Pattern( regex = "really\\?" )`